# Can I get a Schengen visa after being deported from the UK 3 years ago?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, uk, indian-citizens

I'm an Indian national. I was holding a Tier 4 students visa in UK for 2009 to mid of 2011. I was removed to India on working excess of permitted hours, a breach of section 10(1)(a) of the immigration Act 1999 of UK and an offence under section 24(1)(b)(ii) of the immigration Act 1971 of UK. I was served papers IS151A, IS151A part 2, IS91R and been removed by the end of 2010.

1. Will I now have any trouble getting a Schengen visa?
2. What possible steps can I take now to pursue a Schengen visa?
3. Is it true that I am still banned from entering into any countries in the world?

Comment: Just a small addendum to @vartec excellent answer: You are not banned from entering *any* country, just those that work together with the UK on this. Regarding possible steps, etc. this goes beyond what regular travelers might know, the only way to know more would seem to get in touch with a lawyer but I wouldn't have a lot of hope for a quick solution.

Comment: i have idea about SIS and UK's hand in it, but in some condition if i'm suppose to get a visa to United States or Canada then is it still gonna reflect on that too.

Comment: Except if there is some specific agreement between the UK and Canada or the US, they would not usually know about it. There is obviously no global information exchange on these sorts of things (thankfully) and each country remains mostly free to set its own rules in this respect, which means nobody has the authority to ban you from entering any country in the world. US border agents can however google your name and what not so if they do find out in some way, you are right that you might expect some difficulties but they are not bound by this in the way Schengen countries are.

Comment: Did you leave the UK voluntarily after the notice? If yes, then you're banned from re-entry for 1 year. If the UK authorities had to remove you, then you're banned from re-entry for 10 years. Subsequently, the length of the ban will be applied to the rest of SIS subscribers (Schengen countries).

Comment: yes i volunteered. but they paid for the fly. i asked about the ban but they doesn't clarified me.

Answer (score 6):

> Will I have any trouble with getting Schengen visa?

Very likely yes, even though UK is not part of the Schengen zone, it does collaborate in [SIS (Schengen Information System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Information_System)). One of the preconditions of getting a Schengen visa is to not be flagged in SIS.

> In accordance with the protocol to the Treaty of Amsterdam, Ireland
>   and the United Kingdom can take part in some or all of the Schengen
>   arrangements, if the Schengen Member States and the government
>   representative of the country in question vote unanimously in favour
>   within the Council.
>
> In March 1999, the United Kingdom asked to cooperate in some aspects
>   of Schengen, namely police and judicial cooperation in criminal
>   matters, the fight against drugs and the SIS. The Council Decision
>   2000/365/EC approving the request by the United Kingdom was adopted on
>   29 May 2000.
>
> *(source: ["The Schengen area and cooperation"](http://europa.eu/legislation_summaries/justice_freedom_security/free_movement_of_persons_asylum_immigration/l33020_en.htm))*

Comment: I upvoted this answer and commented in the same direction but in fact I don't really know exactly what is recorded in the SIS, what data the UK can access and whether the UK can add entries at all. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Information_System) and the council decision your quote mentions in fact suggest that the UK might not be participating in the part of the SIS recording deportations/removal/expulsions. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @Annoyed: you have me doubting now. It's not 100% clear, but you might be right.

Comment: Deportations, removals and expulsions are *not* registered in SIS anyway, not even by proper Schengen members. Schengen members may enter *entry bans* in SIS, but with the UK not participating fully in n the Schengen agreement, I don't see any reasonable legal route, how a UK entry ban (if one exists) should end up in SIS.

Answer (score 2):

The UK does not share information about deportation to SIS because UK is not in Schengen zone and the treaty does not allow to UK to input any data about deportations unless you have done criminal offence . The UK don have access to input Schengen wide alert about deportations . Please refer sis 2 parliament Question's and answer [image: picture of a written conversation]

Comment: That is information out of 2006, is it still relevant?